# Using grep to filter directories

Tags: bash, unix, grep, find, directory

I'm using `find . -type d` to list all directories in a folder. Now say I'm in my `home` folder.

And something like this is my result:

```
.
./.cache
./.config/junk
./Documents
./Downloads
./.local/share/junk1
./.local/share/junk2
./.mozilla/junk1
./Pictures
./Videos
```

I however do not want those hidden files to appear in the list. Doing `find . -type d | grep -v ./.` is not working. It displays only `.` as output in this case.

Any idea how to filter out those hidden folders?

Comment: `.` matches any character, use `/\.`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
find ...|grep '^./[^.]'
```

btw, `find` has option `regex`, you may consider to use, so that save that `grep` cmd.

e.g.

```
find . -type d -a -regex '^./[^.].*'
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to escape your pattern.

`.` matches any character.

`\.` matches the dot character.

`^exp` matches a pattern beginning with `exp`.

If you want to filter out hidden folders at the base level only:

`find . -type d | grep -v '^\./\.'`

If you want to filter out hidden folders at all depths:

`find . -type d | grep -v '/\.'`